# Show that $f(x+iy)$ is holomorphic if and only if it can be expressed as a polynomial in the single variable $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I am very much new in complex analysis.The following question is given in class. Please help me to solve it. I have tried something myself which is also mentioned. Please help me. Thnx in advance.

> Let $f(x+iy)$ be a polynomial with complex coefficients in $x$ and $y$. Show that $f$ is holomorphic if and only if it can be expressed as a polynomial in the single variable $z$.

So far I have done following:

Considering $z+ \bar z=2x,z-\bar z=2y $

$f(z,\bar z) = \displaystyle \sum_{m\ge 0,n\ge 0} a_{mn}z^m\bar z^n$ Now assuming $f$ analytic I use $f_{\bar z}=0\Rightarrow \displaystyle \sum_{m\ge 0,n\ge 1} a_{mn}z^mn\bar z^{n-1}$ Then putting $z=0$ in above equation I get $a_{01}=0$ So differentianting again partially wrt $\bar z$ and putting $z=0$ we will ultimately get $a_{0k}=0\forall k\in \mathbb N$

So $f(z,\bar z) = \displaystyle \sum_{m\ge 1,n\ge 0} a_{mn}z^m\bar z^n$ But I can not proceed further and has no idea how to prove the converse part also.

Being very new to complex analysis I appologise if I am missing something very simple or doing something verymuch wrong.

Please help me to solve this question. Thnx again.

Comment: Maybe you need to apply the Cauchy Riemann relations between the partial derivatives, which hold iff the function is holomorphic.

Comment: @coffeemath I am very sorry but can you please explain a little bit more?I know Cauchy Riemann relations but how should I use it here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact is that if $f$ is holomorphic, then $f_z$ is holomorphic. Then you may apply your argument again and again and get the result.

Comment: Thank you very very much.I have managed to solve one part of the implication. And for the other part I think single variable polynomial is holomorphic. Am I correct?

Comment: @usermath That's it, since it does not depend on $\bar{z}$.

Comment: Thank you again.Your answer really helped me.Thnx.

Comment: Pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0):

You have already arrived at $a_{0k}=0$ for $k\ge 0.$ So in your notation, this means $f(z,\bar{z})=\sum a_{m0}z^m$ which is already a polynomial in $z$.

It looks like you have already used the Cauchy Riemann equations, which amount to saying the derivative w.r.t. $\bar{z}$ is zero for a holomorphic function.

The "only if" part of the question is just to say that given $f$ is assumed to be a polynomial in $z$ then it is holomorphic, but that's immediate.

In sum, it looks like you already have done the work.